# Pairwise prime triples of integers satisfying $x^2+y^2=z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

The following property has been stated without proof in a problem solving book (not as a problem, hence no solution). I also looked at the number theory text I have, and I cannot find it.

> All pairwise prime triples of integers satisfying $x^2+y^2=z^2$ are given by $$x=|u^2-v^2|\;,\;y=2uv\;,\; z=u^2+v^2\;,\;\text{gcd}(u,v)=1\;,\; u\neq v \;\text{mod} \;2$$

Particularly, why $u,v$ should be coprime ***and*** $u\neq v\; \bmod \;2$ as otherwise this is trivial algebra. 
A reference or an intuitive explanation of this result would be appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering, is "relatively prime" a more common term or "pairwise prime"? had never seen "pairwise prime" before, but it is clear that what it means. Tx

Comment: Google "Pythagorean triple" an you'll find many proofs.

Comment: @Bill the only proofs I see in the wikipedia page is under the section "relation to gaussian integers" and "wiles' proof of fermat's last theorem". Could you point me to the relevant section.

Comment: $\gcd(u, v) = 1$ is clearly a necessary condition. Are you asking why it is sufficient together with $u \neq v \bmod 2$? This is not too difficult an exercise; start thinking about $\gcd(x, y)$.

Comment: For lots of information about Pythagorean Triples consult this web page: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Pythag/pythag.html

Comment: @Qia yup, why $u,v$ should be coprime _and_ have different parity as well. Henry's answers clears everything up.

Comment: I think one can find $\text{a proof of this fact}$ in $\text{ Silverman's : Rational points on elliptic curves}$ book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for the $u$ and $v$ coprime and opposite parity is that you have the expression for *primitive* Pythagorean triples, i.e. those where $x$, $y$ and $z$ have no common factor apart from $1$.  If $u$ and $v$ have a common factor $k$ then $x$, $y$ and $z$ have a common factor $k^2$, while if $u$ and $v$ are both odd then $x$, $y$ and $z$ have a common factor $2$.

To extend these to capture *all* Pythagorean triples, merely multiply the  expressions for $x$, $y$ and $z$ terms by an arbitrary positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

Proving that u and v are coprime is trivial as, if a number k>1 divides both u and v, then it is a factor x that is smaller than x which is a contradiction.If u and v were of the same parity then 2 would be a factor of x which is also a contradiction.